# Reset 'Salesforce for Slack App' from deleted scratch org

Tags: scratch-org, slack-salesforce-app, slack-app

I encountered an issue while testing the 'Salesforce for Slack App' with my scratch org. After deleting the scratch org using the sfdx command, I'm unable to establish a connection between the Salesforce for Slack App and the new org.

Home Home tab is not functioning properly, as it continues to display a loading message.

Any ideas what I can do instead of asking support team?

[image]

Comment: 7 days passed and I have already tried reinstalling